# a cool/chilled experience

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> This is a **cool** experience
>
> This is a **chilled** experience

Are both sentences above on the usage of **a cool/chilled experience**, grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: what do you understand the mean of cool/chilled to be? literal "ie cold" or figurative (ie relaxed"

Comment: @JamesK it’s figurative